# Why does RFECV results vary from iteration to iteration

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, feature-selection, rfe

I'm using RFECV for feature selection and I couldn't help but notice that I would get a different number of features on each run. I have 24 features sometimes the results would say that it only used 9 features sometimes it said 22 features.

I was wondering what's the reason for this and how do I interpret these different results and with which number of features should I go.

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV

rfecv = RFECV(estimator=RandomForestClassifier())
model = RandomForestClassifier()
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('s',rfecv),('m',model)])
# evaluate model
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
n_scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, y, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1, error_score='raise')
# report performance
print('Accuracy: %.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(n_scores), std(n_scores)))
# summarize all features
rfecv.fit(X, y)
#feat = []
for i in range(X.shape[1]):
    print('Column: %d, Selected %s, Rank: %.3f' % (i, rfecv.support_[i], rfecv.ranking_[i]))
```

Comment: You're using a random forest to estimate feature importance, which fits a decision tree on random subsets of your data. That's inherently random - though you can reduce the degree to which it varies by raising the number of trees fit with the `n_estimators` parameter. See also: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html

Comment: @NickODell Thanks for the answer. How do you determine the n_estimators value? Is it a trial and error thing?

Comment: Yes. If you want a more systematic approach, you can look into grid search hyperparameter tuning.